# Annotated Class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, spring-mvc

I am still trying my way around the Hibernate for some time now and I do think that I could make use of this framework rather than the hardcore JDBC approach.

It seems that every tutorial that I have looked at the net nowadays is making use of the annotated style POJO configuration.  As such, I dont have problem with this and it makes coding a lot easier.

But I am having this thought.

Are the POJO that I am annotating, the same POJO that I will used when I need to get data from a user? What I mean is that, when user fills out a web form and I am using Spring MVC.  I normally get a command object that maps to the user entried form.  This is the same command object that I am persisting and these are just POJO's also.

In the Business Layer/Presentation Layer, I think there is a need for a Model Layer. For example, I have a Student Enrollment System. During the ADD Student Use case and in the Add Student form, I normally input the StudentID, First_Name, Last_Name.

In my servlet or in my controller, I usually map the Form Values into a concrete class.  Spring does a good job in packaging the form values into a concrete class.

Sorry if my question might be a little vague but I just wanted to clear my thoughts. Kindly advise if my question still needs some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It can be the same. Arguably, this is the point of having JPA and deprecate Entity Beans.

Other things doesn't have a question tone and looks fine to me, so can't really recognise if you have any other hidden question.

Comment: It can be the same?  Hello sir, I just would like to ask regarding this comment of yours.  Does this mean than on some cases, I need to create POJO class that is oriented towards the Business Layer only and POJO class that is oriented only on the Peristent Hibernate Layer.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Mark: I usually use the same POJO/Entity/Bean, whatever you say, as my TO. Unless and until its required and better to have a separate POJO for presentation. For the latter, suppose I have a web form, which consist of fields from multiple tables, then may be its a good idea to have a separate `FormBean`, or something.

Comment: @Mark: The idea is why need to duplicate the thing. JPA annotations don't hold when in web tier. It would be just another POJO. So, use the same POJO/Entity as a TO, unless required otherwise. The case mentioned by Qwerky, can be handled by documenting the class and methods well, I believe. Simple is better than complex, and complex is better than complicated. Long live The Zen of Python.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking whether you can use the same class to represent an object through all layers of your application, from database (model) to business logic (controller) to presentation (view).

The answer is yes, but be careful. There may be certain aspects of your object that you want to protect, for example do you really want the view to be able to set the ID? While you might think its not a problem, you might change your mind when someone else does maintenance work on the use account page in 6 months time and decides to allow users to change their ID, just because the bean has a `setID()` method.

Comment: Yes sir that is basically my question.  Just a question though, how can I protect my ID from being set at the view layer? My POJO are always using the pattern of having a getter and setter. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Have seperate objects in the data layer (your entity) and everywhere else (a DTO). Use entities only in the data layer and don't let them escape. To this end your DAO method signatures will use DTOs and convert to and from entities internally. Its a bit of a hassle but in certain situations it can be worth it, if you need to program defensively.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply sir.  Just for clarification,  I can code a class named Student and this will serve as a DTO from the View Layer onto the Business Layer.  Then in the Business Layer, I should instantiate a POJO class annotated with Hibernate.  This class will be populated from the data coming from DTO?  So in my case, both DTO and my persistent class will exactly have the same fields only that the latter has annotation.  Is my understanding correct?  Thanks.